# Why do I get ampersand characters in my strings?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, topic, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to fix [an issue](https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/rqt_bag_exporter/issues/21) that appeared on ROS Melodic, I cannot reproduce this on ROS Kinetic.

## In short

- I'm using `QCheckBox` objects and setting the text to a ROS topic name.
- I then retrieve this topic name (from the `QCheckBox`) but ampersand characters randomly appear in the strings.

## Details

Use the [ampersand branch](https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/rqt_bag_exporter/tree/ampersand) to reproduce this bug:

- Compile / launch with command line (`roslaunch rqt_bag_exporter gui.launch`)
- Open [this bag file](https://ufile.io/vhyho)
- Tick `/topic/dog` topic to be exported
- Export

On my machine it fails with:
[image: image description]

The service fails because the topic name has an extra ampersand (`&`) character after the first slash (`/`), I cannot find where this character comes from.

## More info

It is in the `fillTopicsToExport` member that the ampersand first appear, before that all ROS_INFO output display the correct topic name.

```
[ WARN] [1529331726.714089119]: Service server listTopics:
[ INFO] [1529331726.714882690]: /rosout
[ INFO] [1529331726.714903216]: /rosout_agg
[ INFO] [1529331726.714919695]: /topic/dog
[ WARN] [1529331726.715075880]: Topic list retrieved from the service server: 
[ INFO] [1529331726.716353318]: /rosout
[ INFO] [1529331726.716371703]: /rosout_agg
[ INFO] [1529331726.716381502]: /topic/dog
[ WARN] [1529331726.716421088]: Display topics
[ INFO] [1529331726.716500749]: /rosout
[ INFO] [1529331726.716593479]: /rosout_agg
[ INFO] [1529331726.716648656]: /topic/dog
[ WARN] [1529331732.194335365]: fillTopicsToExport
"/&topic/dog"
[ INFO] [1529331732.194412935]: /&topic/dog
```

## Platform:

- Kubuntu 18.04
- ROS Melodic (up to date as of today)
- Qt 5.9.5
- g++ 7.3.0

I have failed to reproduce this behavior in a simple Qt program.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294394/why-do-i-get-ampersand-characters-in-my-strings?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2018-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure you're running into this issue: [[PyQt] QPushButton.text() ampersand issue](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2015-October/036499.html):

> I'm having an issue getting the text from a QPushButton.The text of the
> button is set with:

> ```
> statusButton = QPushButton(translator.translate('rb', "Start"), self)
> ```

> the text appears normally on the button (i.e. without an ampersand), but
> when I get the text with:

> ```
> status = statusButton.text()
> ```

> the string returned is "&Start" instead of "Start".

The most likely reason is that Qt automatically makes the first (non-special) character of a string set as the label in a `QCheckBox` the *shortcut character* ([docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#details) for `QCheckBox`, search for "shortcut").

If you then ask for the label using `.text()`, the return value is the text *with* the `&`, as that is how you would normally indicate which character should be the one registered as the shortcut for that UI element.

---

Edit: to avoid this the nicest approach would probably be to go with an MVC implementation, where the model is a list of strings and the view creates a `QCheckBox` instance for each entity in the model. You would then interact with the model instead of with the `QCheckBox` labels directly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-18**:
Note: the post I linked to refers to PyQt, but the issue would be the same for C++.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-06-18**:
I finally have a clue of what is happening :) I still don't understand when this renaming happens: just after setting the text, retrieving the text is ok, if retrieving in a SLOT then the text is modified. I'll use `setObjectName` instead of the text as this is meant for this kind of usage.